# Pages missing after migration to new server Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

An old client asked me to transfer a website to a new server on digital ocean, away from their old hosting company. I have the entire server configured, the database set up and linked, etc, and have been able to run the usual commands to build in production.

I have a really weird issue that I'm not sure what the root cause of it is and I am not seeing anything in the error logs about it.

The homepage of the site loads correctly, the css and js load correctly, but once I try to go to another page (the only other page a user can get to from the homepage is the login page, it's kind of an intranet thing), I get a 404 error.

Can anyone point me to what to look for regarding what may be causing the login page to be missing? Same issue if I type in the URL for the password reset page.

In order to build I ran:

```
php artisan down
git reset HEAD --hard
git pull

composer install
npm install

npm run production

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan up
```

then changed permissions to the correct chown and chmod for the site files and storage files.

None of the above commands gave me any errors, which is why I am posting here, I'm not sure where to go if there are no errors! None of the articles I've found have the same issue as I do. Thanks!

Edit to add: I know that the database connection is working, so it isn't an issue with the database not being connected. If that were the issue the login page would still display but i'd get an error on attempted login

Comment: you get a Laravel 404 or a webserver 404?

Comment: @lagbox server 404 (nginx if that helps at all)

Comment: sounds like you don't have pretty urls enabled so its not falling back to rewriting to `index.php`

Comment: @lagbox nginx configuration?

Comment: yup, the configuration for that site ... if the request was making it to laravel you would be getting a response from laravel not nginx directly

Comment: @lagbox thank you i'll look into that now!

Comment: @lagbox could there be anything else I'm missing? Everything I'm seeing says to add `/index.php?$query_string` to sites-available/default, i've done so and restarted but still no go

Comment: add your site config

Comment: @lagbox do you mean the general nginx site config pointing to the correct root etc? That is already set up and works and points to the index correctly if that's what you mean

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment#nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by replacing

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$query_string =404;`

with

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`